¿Cómo soluciono el error NoReverseMatch at /?
ERROR: 

NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'carro' not found. 'carro' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 5.1.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'carro' not found. 'carro' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 831, in _reverse_with_prefix
Raised during:  PapeleraPatriciosApp.views.index

urls:
from django.urls import path

from carro import views

app_name="carro"

urlpatterns = [

    path('',views.carro, name="Carro"),

    path('agregar/<int:producto_id>/', views.agregar_producto, name="agregar"),
    path('eliminar/<int:producto_id>/', views.eliminar_producto, name="eliminar"),
    path('restar/<int:producto_id>/', views.restar_producto, name="restar"),
    path('limpiar/', views.limpiar_carro, name="limpiar"),
    
]

html:
<div class="login">
        <ul>
            <li class="login_list"><button class="login_item" ><a href="#"><img src="{% static 'PapeleraPatriciosApp/images/login.png'%}" alt="login"></a></button></li>
            <li class="login_list"><button class="login_item" ><a href="{% url  'carro'%}"><img src="{% static 'PapeleraPatriciosApp/images/carrito.png'%}" alt=""></a></button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


Y el nombre es "carro" o "Carro" ?!

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Seguro que en la url estás usando una clase, si es así  cambia:
path('',views.carro, name="Carro"),

cambialo por
path('',views.carro.as_view(), name="Carro"),

si eso no funciona prueba con:
path('',views.Carro.as_view(), name="Carro"),

para entender mejor tu problema tienes que subir tambien el views.py.
